# Redirecting HTTPS to HTTP without purchasing another IP address

Tags: seo, htaccess, ip-address, security-certificate

So in the past I have always bought a new IP when working with SSL certs. I came across a client that is on a shared IP and using a cert for one of the sites but not the others. So domain #1 has cert on it, and Domain #2 doesn't.

Domain #2 has things in Google indexed with HTTPS on them. I need to block HTTPS on domain #2 as it shouldn't be using it and I don't want HTTPS versions of pages appearing in Google's index.

How can I go about doing this without purchasing another IP?
Is dropping the below code into my *.htaccess* file a good approach?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: See [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/481738/how-to-disable-https-access-to-specific-virtual-hosts).  Do it at the Server Level instead as Shared IP usually denotes Virtual Hosting

Answer (score 1):

That approach should work fine so long as your Apache config is setup so your application is listening on both ports 80 and 443

However, the original requests will show a warning about not have a valid SSL certificate. See the answer E Carter Young linked to in his comment if you need to avoid that.